# Teamcity auto generate information to dashboard

Tags: teamcity

I have a Teamcity build that is run manually by non-technical people. These users supply runtime values to the build via environment variable prompts. These values are used to orchestrate the build actions and then, when the build is finished (assuming success), I need to output some information to the user regarding the results of the build (loosely, the build creates some websites, so the URLs of these are the output). Ideally, I also need to tag the build so that another user can visit the dashboard later and quickly find the build and the aforementioned output.

I'm using Teamcity version 7.1.3

So, a two-part question:

Firstly, is it possible to add tags or comments to a build in Teamcity, in any other way than manually doing it after the build has run?

If not, then secondly, is there a way to auto-produce any "comment-like" output to the dashboard of a particular build?

I've attempted to do so via [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity):

```
"You can use special progress messages to mark long-running parts in a build script. 
These messages will be shown on the projects dashboard for corresponding build and 
on the build results page.

To log single progress message use:"

##teamcity[progressMessage '<message>']
```

but when doing so, I can only get this to output the message to the build log, not the dashboard.

I could also accomplish this via pushing out a text file artifact, but i'd like to know if a non-artifact approach is possible first.

Any advice most welcome - please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you output it to Build Number Format? In the screenshot I use %build.vcs.number% you can use your variable     (By Dashboard I assume you mean the Overview page)

[image: Build Number Format]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need the build number spot for the actual build number.